# Can we change keyboards programmatically

Tags: iphone

Can we change keyboards programmatically.
can we give user option to change keyboard to different language from application at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible - a user can only change their language in the settings.

However you can give the user an "English" keyboard if you choose (or ask them their preference) - you do this using: UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable